# Saving inputed Data to File

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am making a small application, like a travel agency app, and I was wondering how you could send inputted information (from a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("")`) type of input. I need it to be sent to a file, where I can later retrieve it, like a database. Any ideas?

Code:

```
public boolean action (Event e, Object o)
{
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter your first name: ");
    String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter your last name: ");
    String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter your address: ");
    String telephone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter your telephone num: ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Plenty, but may be you could start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [JDBC basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) and try something

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you know if BufferedReader would work in this situation?

Comment: That depends on how the data is written and how you want to interact with it, but it is certainly possible

Comment: Please **stop** adding the [tag:console] to your questions, and please ***read*** the tag pop-ups before adding them to a post.  This is so far the 3rd of your posts from which I have removed this irrelevant tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous SO question. Basically, you just print your strings into an output.

[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)

Comment: Or you could store in XML or JSON or a single user/stand alone database or through a database server...

Comment: Thanks, I knew the answer was out there somewhere, I guess I wasn't specific enough in my Google search ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Given this is an applet, you might want to look into [cookies](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109) and the HTML5 [webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).  Either can be used from a sand-boxed applet.

Note that to use a local DB or a `File` would require a fully signed and trusted applet.

Comment: As an aside, I think you are being a little to quick to accept answers..  There is a lot of 'less than optimal' advice offered when it comes to applets.  :-/